# firebaseでwebサイトを表示したい

Tags: firebase, google-cloud

teratailでも質問投稿したのですが、答えにたどり着けずに
こちらにも投稿しました、すいません。
GCPでfirebaseを勉強しているんですが
[firebaseスタティックな Web ページをデプロイしたい](https://www.topgate.co.jp/firebase04-firebase-hosting-deploy-website)
というサイトを見て勉強しています。
で早くも詰まりました
まず

```
yum install epel-release
yum install nodejs
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

入れた後

```
firebease login
```

でその方法は [Cloud9からfirebase loginする時のエラー回避の方法](https://blog.f-arts.work/archives/817)
でやり、あとはサイト情報通りやっているんですが
welcome Firebase Hosting Completeの画面は出たのですが
その後public ディレクトリ内の index.html ファイル内容を以下のように変更します。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Firebase Hosting</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, Firebase Hosting!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

で変更して、firebase deployをしてますが、welcome Firebase Hosting Completeのままです。
誰か反映される方法を教えてください。
根本的にまちがっていたら是非指摘してください。
よろしくお願いします

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/185559

Comment: その通りです。すいません。質問自体消したほうがいいなら消します。

Comment: SOは特に禁止していませんし、問題ないですよ。別サイトに有益な回答がある場合など参照しやすいようリンクを張らせてもらっています。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: Firebase コンソールの[開発] > [Hosting] の[デプロイ履歴] にはデプロイコマンドを実行したときの履歴は出ていますか？

Comment: デプロイコマンドを実行したときの履歴は出ています。
特にエラーもでていませんし。
GCPでやっているからでしょうか？localだとうまくいくのでしょうか？

Comment: 参考サイト通りのように、「index.html」を変更してデプロイが成功しているならば、デプロイ履歴には履歴が2つあると思いますが、2つありますか？
また、過去のものにロールバックしていないですか？

Comment: 確認してみたんですが
2つあって2つとも同じでした。
過去のものをロールバックもしてなかったです。

Comment: index.html以外に別のページを追加してデプロイしてみてはどうでしょうか？
別ページが表示されるかどうかで、デプロイの問題なのか
キャッシュの問題なのかとかがわかるかもしれません

Comment: ちょっと試してみます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: もう少し勉強して、もう少しわかってからまたわからないところがでたら質問したいと思います。
みなさんありがとうございました。